# Proof that if $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ then $\frac{x_n}{x_n +1}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ then the sequence $\frac{x_n}{x_n +1}$ converges.

Here is my attempt:
We know that $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ so for every $M$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $k \geq N,$ $x_k \geq M$. Write $\lvert \frac{M}{M+1}\rvert < \epsilon $ for $\epsilon > 0.$ Solving, we get $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < M.$

How do I connect this back to $N$? Or is this a complete proof, given that I have found a relation between $\epsilon$ and $M$?

Comment: you can write $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_n}}$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. How does that help?

Comment: if $x_n$ goes to infinity then $1/x_n$ goes to zero

Comment: I understand how to compute the limit, but I want to give a rigorous proof.

Comment: then $\frac{1}{x_k}\le M$

Answer (score 4):

For all $n \ge N$,

$$\left\lvert 1 - \frac{x_n}{1 + x_n}\right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{1}{1 + x_n}\right\rvert = \frac{1}{1 + x_n} \le \frac{1}{1 + M} < \frac{1}{M}$$

Since $M$ is an arbitrary positive number, so is $\frac{1}{ M}$. Thus $\frac{x_n}{1 + x_n}$ converges to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x_n}{1+x_n} - \frac{x_m}{1+x_m} \right| = \left| \frac{x_n-x_m}{(1+x_n)(1+x_m)}\right|\leq \frac{2\max(|x_n|, |x_m|)}{(1+x_n)(1+x_m)}<
\frac{2}{\min(|1+x_n|, |1+x_m|)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following calculation: $\frac{x_n}{x_n + 1} = \frac{x_n}{x_n} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x_n}} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x_n}}$. Letting $n \to \infty$ gives therefore: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_n + 1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x_n}} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} 1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x_n})} = \frac{1}{1 + 0} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$; The third-to-last equality is due to the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$, so the reciprocal term $\frac{1}{x_n}$ will tend to zero as $n$ tends to infinity.